# Redirect to HTTPS with no www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

After installing HTTPS on my server, and installing the [Really Simple SSL plugin](https://really-simple-ssl.com/) in Wordpress my site now makes correct redirection from HTTP to HTTPS in this cases:

- `www.example.org` is redirected to `https://example.org`
- `example.org` is redirected to `https://example.org`
- `http://example.org` is redirected to `https://example.org`

But I have many links that before the SSL installation pointed to `http://www.example.org`, and now try to acces `https://www.example.org`, **having a insecure connection erron** in here.

Is there any way of removing always the www from the URL through the `.htaccess`, or any other way of archieving this? This is my `.htaccess` config:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: It would be good to have your SSL certificate for both, if possible

Comment: Thank you @Jeff, it is possible but I am afraid of being penalized by search engines for duplicate URLs... Is there any alternative to this? Thank you-.

Comment: WordPress will still redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com` for you.  It's just an issue of the order right now - it's trying to add the `https` BEFORE it's removing the `www`.  So if you had both secure, it would go `http://www.example.com` -> 301 `https://www.example.com` -> 301 `https://example.com`.  2 quick redirects is not a problem for SEO

Comment: Thank you Jeff, would it be possible to reorder those steps through the .htaccess? As seen here: https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/08/redirect-domain-http-https-www-apache/

Comment: Yes. Try what is suggested in the article you linked.

Comment: I was trying. Same result, no success. I am afraid that the only solution is the one you mentioned, as already saw on other similar questions. Its hard for me to believe this can not be changed by default...

Comment: Please add your aditional SSL certificate suggestion as a reply, I'll check in case no other solution comes in. Thank you :)

Comment: What have you added to your .htaccess, can you post that? It should work just fine. Adding the certificate for www.example.com should solve it as well (that was @Jeff, though, not me). Btw, you'll usually be able to use the same certificate for www.example.com and example.com.